# Password gen and input doesnt work

Tags: java, password-generator

I tried to make a random password gen, and then you had to input the random password which had to be exactly the same, but the problem is, that it will always say: Passwords didn't match. So even if the paswords match, it still doesnt work... If I inverse it (So "if(!scanner.equals(random)){") it says it works, but that only inverses it, so that is not weird XD Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class V20ControlPanel {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    Random random = new Random();

    final String alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    final int N = alphabet.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.print(alphabet.charAt(random.nextInt(N)));

    }

    String s;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     s = scanner.nextLine();

    if (random.equals(scanner)) {
        System.out.println("You've succesfully logged in! With password: " +s);
    } else {
        System.out.println("The passwords didn't match, please try again.");


    }
}
```

}

Comment: First, how can `Random` equal a `Scanner`? Second, no where did you assign the random password to something, you only printed out the characters. Third, I think you will want to compare to `s` (which is read from system.in), not `scanner`. Finally, make sure that `s` is exactly what you expect by debugging it.

Comment: The Input of the scanner has to equal the random, s just reads the input and outputs it if the scanner equals the random generated password.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing a `Random` object to a `Scanner` object, not the values you want to get. Declare a local variable to hold what the password should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Random random = new Random();

    final String alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    final int N = alphabet.length();
    String pass = ""; //The variable to hold the password
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pass += alphabet.charAt(random.nextInt(N)); //Add to password
    }

    String s;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     s = scanner.nextLine();

    if (pass.equals(s)) { //Changed
        System.out.println("You've succesfully logged in! With password: " +s);
    } else {
        System.out.println("The passwords didn't match, please try again.");


    }
}
```

This is still pretty inefficient code, though. You might consider ways to more effectively generate a random `String`.

Comment: One way to make it more efficient would be to use a `StringBuilder`. Better way, since size is known up front, is to use `char[]`. Either of which you could have shown, without much work, instead of the inefficient code you did show. Still: +1.